# How to convert this numpy one-liner into Tensorflow backend code?

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, keras, backend, loss

I have multiple depthmaps which show a car from different angles. I need to calculate how well they match together in my loss function, so I have to reproject them into a different view. The depthmaps live in a cube that is relative to the length of the vehicle. The images have the shape (256,256). I already wrote the code to convert them to a pointcloud with backend functions (256*256,3). I can reproject this pointcloud to the side view with numpy like this:

```
reProj = np.zeros((256, 256), np.float32)
reProj[pointCloud[:, 1], pointCloud[:, 2]] = pointCloud[:, 0]
```

How can I convert this into keras backend code? I suspect there should be a gather somewhere in there, but I just cannot get it working.

**Example:**

**Source depth image:**

[image]

**Reprojected:**

[image]

Thanks for your help!

Edit: Minimal working example with data: https://easyupload.io/rwutwa

Comment: Are you ok with tensorflow functions, or do you want to only use `tf.keras.backend` ?

Comment: Also, do you have a guarantee that `pointCloud[:,0]` and `pointCloud[:,1]` covers all indexes of your array?

Comment: Can I use tensorflow functions in my loss function? I dont have much experience in this, but from what I read you can only use backend functions? Yes, [:,0] and [:,1] cover all indexes of the array.

Comment: You can definitely use TensorFlow functions in your loss function. However, you will be limited to run keras with the tensorflow backend.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I just realized that I lied about the indicies, [:,1] contains the depth data, so it only covers a portion of the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i finally figured it out, I was just thinking about it wrong. It is not a gather operation, is it a scatter. This works perfect now!

```
indices = K.stack([p[:, 1], p[:, 2]], -1)
indices = K.reshape(indices, (256, 256, 2))
indices = K.clip(indices, 0, 256 - 1)
updates = K.reshape(p[:,0], (256,256))
reProj = tf.tensor_scatter_nd_max(tf.zeros((256, 256), tf.int32), indices, updates)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using `tf.matmul()` the first input will be your pointcloud, from the dimensions i am assuming you are storing for every pixel a 3d vector x,y,z. The second input will be the 3d rotation matrix coresponding to the projection you need, keep in mind this works for every angle you want to you just need to define the 3x3 matrix.

If i understand correctly your data you need to rotate over x 90 degrees so the matrix would be

```
1 0 0
0 0 -1
0 1 0
```

read more on rotation matrices here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix
just go to the tree dimension and see what you need